# PreferenceFragment keeps crashing in Instantiation

Tags: android

In my Android App, I implemented Settings Page with AppCompatPreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment. In Crashlytics I found lots of devices crashed when PreferenceFragment is instantiated with the following message:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public.
```

However, I'm pretty sure in fragment I did implement an empty constructor and both PreferenceFragment and AppCompatPreferenceActivity are both "public" so How else should I do to prevent this from crashing again?

Besides I've also put this in my pro-guard rules:

```
-keep public class * extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```